# How do i connect keyboard to textfield and make textfield always stay in foreground? How to wrap ListView.builder content?

Tags: android, flutter

So, i am trying to programm a simple Notes App.
It should open the Keyboard onto a TextField on app start-up and when i click the back button it should just minimize the keyboard but make the TextField stay on the foreground on the bottom of the screen.

1. How can i wrap the content in the ListView.builder, so that it occupies only the amount of space, that the notes need?
2. How can i make a textfield always stay in the foreground on the bottom of the screen?
3. Is it possible that i connect the keyboard layout and the textfield? So that when i click on the textfield, it opens up the keyboard from the bottom and pushes up the textfield with it and doesnt just open the keyboard above the textfield and thus hiding it in the background?

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<String> notes = ["Note1", "Note2", "Note4", "Note5"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Notizen App",
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[700],
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: notes.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                      child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        onTap: () {},
                        title: Text(notes[index]),
                        trailing: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              notes.removeAt(index);
                            });
                          },
                          child: Text("Delete"),
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ));
                }),
          ),
          TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: 2,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter brilliant idea"),
            autofocus: true,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqoK8.png)

Comment: Please limit your posts to one question per post. Piling all your questions into a single post can make it difficult for people to give good quality answers, and will make it harder for people in the future to find your question if they have a similar issue.

Comment: ah ok. sorry! and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After discussing with @Abion I have tested the following code and it's working.

```
 class _MyHomePageState extends State<Home> {
  int _counter = 0;


  List<String> notes = ["Note1", "Note2", "Note4", "Note5","Note6"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Notizen App",
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[700],
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: notes.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {},
                    title: Text(notes[index]),
                    trailing: FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          notes.removeAt(index);
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text("Delete"),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ));
                }),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 0,
            child: Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter brilliant idea"),
                  autofocus: true,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! i will try that tomorrow.

Comment: Guessing widget sizes in Flutter is usually a sign that you are using Flutter widgets wrong. In this case, using `Column` and `Expanded` is better than hard-coding widget heights.

Comment: In this case it would not be an issue because the textfield height is fixed. Being specific only to this question I tested the code it's working. If you kindly check the expanded or flexible and the flex values doc they are the same concepts, just in a new name and polished. You can say it's bad practice but it's not wrong. @Abion47

Comment: Bad practice generally implies you are using the tools wrong. Hardcoding widget heights (especially in a way that is not directly related to the widget itself) leads to fragile UI that will only work on the device it was developed on, and will either look broken or will actually break when an end user views it on a device with a different resolution or screen ratio. Simply replacing the outer `ListView` with `Column` and replacing the `Container` with an `Expanded` achieves the same result without having to rely on fragile magic numbers by letting Flutter do the layout work for you.

Comment: But to answer all the 3 questions I had to declare a height otherwise it's not working. I agree with you and I know that already. Thanks

Comment: And also the textfield height is fixed so resolution won't be a problem this time. Using expanded and flexible is not solving all the questions.

Comment: Have you tried it? I've copied your code into a project and made only the changes that I mentioned and it is working fine to satisfy all 3 questions with no hard-coding of the text field height. And no, a fixed height will look different on screens with different resolutions and/or screen ratios.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220644/discussion-between-amon-chowdhury-and-abion47).

Comment: thank you guys very much. helpin a noobie like me :D

Comment: You will rock. Please set the answer as a correct answer it will help other developers too.